# colons and question marks at end of variable

Tags: syntax

I don't really know how to call them but when looking at others' source code I frequently see this:

```
side = backFace ? WEST   : EAST;
mask[n++] = (0    <= x[d]      ? f(x[0],      x[1],      x[2])      : false)!=
      (x[d] <  dims[d]-1 ? f(x[0]+q[0], x[1]+q[1], x[2]+q[2]) : false);
```

when variables are mentioned, what does the `?` and `:` mean? For some reason I never learned about these and never fully understood what they mean, does it have something to do with the value of the variable?

also if someone knows their official name i would gladly correct the title...

Comment: Find "ternary operator" using any search site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typically called a ternary conditional operator, although the exact name may depend on the language you are using.

Comment: ok thanks for the quick answer, i will mark this as the answer ASAP